# ColumnText.ShowTextAligned

Tags: itext

There are two PDF-documents - A.pdf and B.pdf. They have the same page size. 
I add an object Phrase to the page in both documents.

```
Stamper_A:=New PdfStamper(reader_A,  
             New System.IO.FileStream(
                 out_file1, 
                 System.IO.FileMode.CreateNew));

ContentByte_A:=Stamper_A.GetOverContent(2);
ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(
    ContentByte_A, 
    Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 
    phrase, 
    75, 
    680, 
    0);

Stamper_B:=New PdfStamper(reader_B,  New System.IO.FileStream(out_file2, System.IO.FileMode.CreateNew));
ContentByte_A:=Stamper_B.GetOverContent(2);
ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(ContentByte_B, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, phrase, 75, 680,0);
```

But in the document out_file1 Phrase is higher than in the document out_file2.
Why is this happening?

Comment: Please supply the PDFs in question for an accurate answer. You should be aware, though, that different PDFs (actually even different pages in the same PDF) might have differing coordinate systems for positioning objects in spite of having eventually the same page size.

Answer (score 2):

A.pdf and B.pdf have either a different MediaBox and/or a different CropBox.

Comment: Ok, i understand. Please tell me, how to insert text in the same absolute position in both documents?

Comment: First try getting the Rectangle of the CropBox. Most of the times this will return null (because a CropBox is optional). In that case, get the normal page size (there's ALWAYS a MediaBox). Once you have this Rectangle, use rect.left() and rect.bottom() as the origin of your coordinate system. So if you want to add something at position x, y, use rect.left() + x and rect.bottom() + y as coordinates.